# critical points of $~f(x) = e^{\frac x2} - e^{\frac x3}\sin(3x)~$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Can you think of ways to identify the critical points of the function $$f(x) = e^{\frac{x}{2}} - e^{\frac{x}{3}}\sin(3x)$$ without using a graph (already tried the standard method of taking derivative and setting it equal to zero)?

Comment: You have it in your tag... Take the derivative!

Comment: ...after taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero, sorry the post should be edited shortly.

Comment: As mentioned above, you have to take the derivatives, and figure out when x = 0. On equation form this is when f'(x) = 0. Looks like you need to recall the product rule and the chain rule of differentiation.